# Can I access a belongsTo property from within a beforeDelete() event?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given these domain classes:

```
class Team {
  hasMany = [players: Player, logsEntries: LogEntry]
}

class Player {
  belongsTo = [team: Team]
  def beforeDelete() {
    team.addToLogEntries('player deleted')
  }
}

class LogEntry {
  belongsTo = [team: Team]
}
```

I get an exception in `beforeDelete` saying that `team` is `null`. I also tried wrapping the contents of `beforeDelete` with `LogEntry.withNewSession { ... }` but the error persists.

Any ideas if what I'm trying to do is possible?

---

EDIT: It is kinda making sense when I consider how I delete `players`:

```
def team = Team.get(id)
playersToDelete.each {
  team.removeFromPlayers(it)
  it.delete()
}
```

So I break the relationship before `beforeDelete` gets called so `team` is `null`. However, I did try to change the order (`delete()` and then `removeFromPlayers` and that didn't help. I also tried to set `all-delete-orphan` for `players` on `Team` domain. That didn't help either :(

Comment: Share your exeception. Since you declared belongsTo and hasMany the delete will be cascade.

Comment: The exception says `cannot call removeFromPlayers on a null object`.